# Center nav-items inside nav container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm struggling with centering the content of a nav-item inside nav container in my project. 
I can't put a margin on the ul>li items, because it's not working on a different resolution.
I need something in percentage maybe, but I tried and nothing worked.
The expected result is something like this 
[image]

You can find a little demo [here](https://www.codeply.com/go/SDt3vCBukc)

Thanks a lot in advance,
Andreea.

```css
.header-nav-fixed-down {
  height: 60px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #2c3642;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.divider {
  width: 1px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

div#navbarCollapse ul li a{
    color: grey !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Bootstrap 4 Navbar with hover multi dropdown</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <link href="css/bootstrap-4-hover-navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">


       
    </head>
    <body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-down header-nav-fixed-down ">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto">
            <li class=" nav-item ">
                <a href="#">ItemA</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider m-auto"></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                 <a href="#">ItemB.1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#">ItemB.2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                 <a href="#">ItemB.3</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        </ul>
        
        <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                 <a href="#">ItemB.1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#">ItemB.2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                 <a href="#">ItemB.3</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        </ul>
       
        <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                 <a href="#">ItemD</a>
            </li>
           
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        </ul>
         <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                 <a href="#">ItemE1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                 <a href="#">ItemE2</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        </ul>
         <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto">
            <li class="nav-item ">
                 <a href="#">ItemF1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item ">
                 <a href="#">ItemF2</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>








        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script src="js/bootstrap-4-hover-navbar.js"></script>
    

</body></html>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not a free coding service

Comment: @Gobbin : I tried to put the ul in a table and the li in the table-cell, not worked. I've put also margins on the li items, like margin-right/left 40px, but on different screen resolutions, is not ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-down header-nav-fixed-down ">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto">
            <li class="nav-item border-right px-4 ">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">ItemA</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item px-4 ">
                 <a class="nav-link" href="#">ItemB.1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item px-4 ">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">ItemB.2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item border-right px-4 ">
                 <a class="nav-link" href="#">ItemB.3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item px-4 ">
                 <a class="nav-link" href="#">ItemC.1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item px-4 ">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">ItemC.2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item border-right px-4 ">
                 <a class="nav-link" href="#">ItemC.3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item border-right px-4 ">
                 <a class="nav-link" href="#">ItemD</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item border-right px-4 ">
                 <a class="nav-link" href="#">ItemE1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item border-right px-4 ">
                 <a class="nav-link" href="#">ItemE2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item px-4 ">
                 <a class="nav-link" href="#">ItemF1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item px-4 ">
                 <a class="nav-link" href="#">ItemF2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

There was no need for the amount of `<ul class="navbar-nav">` elements. If you don't want the border on all of the elements then just remove border right where applicable.

You were also missing the class of `nav-link` for the nested anchors. If the item isn't to be a link you can use the `nav-text` class.

Comment: If you look closely, you will see that the separator is added only sometimes. ItemA, is a category, after that, I have to add a separator. Item B1, B2, B3 is a category, after all these 3 items, I have to add another separator.

Comment: Would you not be better using the likes of a dropdown menu then? Item A > its contents and so on?

Comment: This is the mockup that I received from the team :)

Comment: @AndreeaDumitru Edited answer - as I stated before use the `border-right` where necessary and you'll get the dividers you require.

Comment: If you change the resolution of the screen, the items are going out of the navbar. I played also with the padding, is not working.

Comment: I advise you go take an example navbar from http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/navbars/ and adapt it to how necessary.

Comment: The idea is that I've started from exactly that link. And already lost more than 8 hours with this...

Answer (score 0):

You could use Flexbox for the nav container.  What this will do will allow the items within the nav container to 'flex' and give's you the ability to control their direction (vertical, horizontal) and their general position (start, center, end).  The best part is that it is responsive, so when the screen size changes, your children (list items within the nav) will flex and fit into the available space around them.  You could try the below to get started.

```
.navigation {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-evenly;
   align-items: center;
 }
```